# how to do a find query without json-parsing the result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Some of our queries returns large array of big JSON documents.

Those queries are directly send back to the client as stringified JSON.

Parsing and immediately stringifying those documents can be quite expensive (a few hundred MS per query). And it is totaly useless.

Is there a way to direcly get a stringified JSON response from mongo ?

This way we can direcly forward a stringified response to our client.

Thanks

Comment: No. That is what the rest of your stack ( presumably http server at least ) is for. The "database" does "database stuff" and nothing else.

Comment: MongoDB servers return results in [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) (a JSON-like binary data structure), which drivers convert into language-specific object types. There is no native JSON reponse type. Since your question is tagged with Mongoose, I suspect what you mean be looking for is the `lean` query option: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean. This returns plain JavaScript objects and removes the overhead of converting query results into MongooseDocuments. Your app could then use `JSON.stringify()` to return the response to the client.